# Send data from JavaScript to a svg file

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, mqtt

I'm using Node.js and a svg file

What I want, it's to send specific value (from Node.js) to the specific line in svg file

The file findTopic.js is a script who read a svg file and find topic like

```
"{ + content + }"
```

And then push him in a array.

I've got a data.js file:

```
const listTickets = require("../scripts/findTopic.js");
// output ['{garage/temp}', '{home/sensors/temp/kitchen}']

var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var options = {
    //*** 
};
var client = mqtt.connect('***', options);
client.on('connect', function () { // When connected
    console.log('connected');
    // subscribe to a topic
    
    for( let i = 0 ; i < listTickets.allTopics().length; i++){
        const topicSelected = listTickets.allTopics()[i];
        var newTopic = topicSelected.substring(1, topicSelected.length - 1);
        console.log(newTopic); // output: garage/temp home/sensors/temp/kitchen
        client.subscribe(newTopic, { qos: 0 });
        client.on("message", function (topic, message) {
            console.log(message.toString()); //output: 24 24
        });
        client.end(); 
    }
});
```

And I've got a svg file:

```
<svg width="500" height="100">
    <circle id="circle1" cx="20" cy="20" r="10"
            style="stroke: none; fill: #ff0000;"/>  
    <text x="47.872" y="11.064" >{garage/temp} °C</text>
    <circle id="circle1" cx="20" cy="20" r="10"
            style="stroke: none; fill: #ff0000;"/>
    <text x="47.872" y="11.064" >{home/sensors/temp/kitchen} °C</text>
    <circle id="circle1" cx="20" cy="20" r="10"
            style="stroke: none; fill: #ff0000;"/>
</svg>
```

So now how can I change {garage/temp} and {home/sensors/temp/kitchen} by the value 24 and 24 into my navigator to my data.js file?

Comment: You should only be setting the `client.on('message',...)` event handler once, probably outside the `client.on('connect',...)` handler. Also calling `client.end()` in the for loop makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

How do you reference the SVG document (because I don't know the MQTT) e.g. say you name the variable reference as svg?

When you know that it would be a simple:

```
var texts = svg.getElementsByTagName("text");
for (i=0; i<texts.length; i++) {
  texts[i].replace(listTickets.allTopics()[i], message.toString());
}
```

or something similar (you don't have to create a new variable if you just need to replace a content of a list element).

The above assumes that TEXT elements in your SVG file are all variable templates e.g. there are no other TEXT elements. If there are then you should use if statement to compare texts[i] inner content to your listTickets current index content (in a loop) and if there is a match replace it etc.